# Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android

Having some trouble, this was weird because out of nowhere I'm getting this error:
If you do help me, thanks in advance! I don't think it is coming from the php, I suspect the LoginActivity or LoginRequest! 
Full Error Code:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
W/System.err:     at com.tonikamitv.loginregister.LoginActivity$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:46)
W/System.err:     at com.tonikamitv.loginregister.LoginActivity$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:42)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

LoginActivity.java:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppAd;
import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppSDK;
import com.startapp.android.publish.video.VideoListener;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        final TextView tvRegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterLink);
        final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSignIn);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String username = sharedPref.getString("username", "");
        String password = sharedPref.getString("password", "");

        if (username.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0) {
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {
                            String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                            String username = jsonResponse.getString("username");
                            String password = jsonResponse.getString("password");

                            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                            editor.putString("username", username);
                            editor.putString("password", password);
                            editor.apply();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("name", name);
                            intent.putExtra("username", username);
                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);

            tvRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
                }
            });

            bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                    final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

                    // Response received from the server
                    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                                if (success) {
                                    String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                                    String username = jsonResponse.getString("username");

                                    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                                    editor.putString("username", username);
                                    editor.putString("password", password);
                                    editor.apply();

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                    intent.putExtra("username", username);
                                    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                } else {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                    builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                            .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                            .create()
                                            .show();
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                    queue.add(loginRequest);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

LoginRequest.java:

```
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://gamerduo1.byethost15.com/Login.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Login.php:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id177667_root", "***", "id177667_loginb");

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $username, $password, $points, $time);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;  
        $response["name"] = $name;
        $response["username"] = $username;
        $response["password"] = $password;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: is your server up and running ? try testing request from postman see what response do you get . because here in the error log is saying you aren't getting JSON response from server

Comment: Never used Postman before, because I haven't run into many errors that couldn't be fix easily,

Comment: I use postman when i cant figure out what is the response i'm getting from server and your error reminds me of one i got when my server was down and i used spring on my server and it responded and HTML stack trace.

Comment: if you want to be sure of the response its a very good and free to use app and you can get it from [here](https://www.getpostman.com)